# Java Aws sdk 2 connection and async calls

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, proxy, aws-sdk

I'm trying to write to an S3 bucket **asynchronously** through proxy locally and else through EC2 instance using Java aws sdk 2 library.

I was able to create  sync client but **ASYNC** seems  different ball game all together.

Here's code what i'm using  to connect locally using iam keys and else EC2 instance:
     Region region = Region.of(awsS3Config.getRegion());
           if (goalsEngineConfig != null && ENVIRONMENT_LOCAL.equalsIgnoreCase(goalsEngineConfig.getEnv()))
            {
                AwsCredentials
                    awsCredentials =
                    AwsCredentials.create(awsS3Config.getIamKey(), awsS3Config.getIamSecretKey());

```
            String protocol = Protocol.HTTP.toString();
            String host = "somproxy.foo";
            int port = 8888;
            String path = null;
            String auth = null;
            String fragment = null;
            URI uri = new URI(protocol, auth, host, port, path, null, fragment);
            ProxyConfiguration.Builder builder = ProxyConfiguration.builder().endpoint(uri);
            ProxyConfiguration proxyConfiguration = builder.build();

            ApacheSdkHttpClientFactory
                apacheSdkHttpClientFactory =
                ApacheSdkHttpClientFactory.builder().proxyConfiguration(proxyConfiguration).build();

            this.s3Client = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .httpConfiguration(ClientHttpConfiguration.builder()
                    .httpClientFactory(apacheSdkHttpClientFactory)
                    .build())
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
                .build();

            SdkAsyncHttpClientFactory sdkAsyncHttpClientFactory = null;
            SdkAsyncHttpClient sdkHttpClient = null;
```

//Creating **Async** NOT WORKING so i need help creating it
                this.s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .asyncHttpConfiguration(ClientAsyncHttpConfiguration.builder()
                       .httpClient(sdkHttpClient)
                      .build()) .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCredentials))
                    .build();
            }
            else //not local env, use EC2 instance authentication
            {
this.s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.builder()
                    .region(region)
                    .credentialsProvider(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
                    .build();
            }

Any help is welcome ?

Comment: So what is the exact issue here, from what I understand you want to do a Java SDK Async S3 GET, but you don't know how to connect to AWS S3 with the AWS Java SDK that supports Async?

Comment: I'd like to do PUT (see edited code) sorry i thought i pasted the correct snippet  and @MattG that's correct i'm not sure how to connect to AWS S3 with the AWS Java SDK 2 that supports Async especially around the proxy part .

Comment: It [sounds](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/858) like this may not be supported in the Java SDK V2  client (yet)